# Unable to install NuGet packages on Rider, available packages are outdated

Tags: nuget, rider

I've freshly installed Pop!_OS on my laptop, installed latest dotnet sdk using apt ([using these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1904)) and installed Rider using snap.

I'm failing to install any NuGet packages using Rider, for instance I tried looking for FluentAssertions and Rider lists 4.17.0 as latest version, while really 5.9.0 is the latest one. If I try to install even the outdated version, I get the following exception:

```
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /jonnyzzz/MonoRuntime/Unix/mono/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00048] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronously, Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00262] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c3] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00102] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00322] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00089] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Uri authUri, System.Net.ICredentials credentials, System.Boolean preAuthenticate, System.Boolean isProxyAuth, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool pool, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00112] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ba] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ca] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.ServerWarningLogHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0007f] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.StsAuthenticationHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000bc] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceAuthenticationHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c1] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x000b3] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.TimeoutUtility.StartWithTimeout[T] (System.Func`2[T,TResult] getTask, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.String timeoutMessage, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001bd] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandler.SendAsync (NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandlerRequest request, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x004a0] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetThrottledResponse (System.Func`1[TResult] requestFactory, System.TimeSpan requestTimeout, System.TimeSpan downloadTimeout, System.Int32 maxTries, System.Guid sessionId, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d6] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1[T].<GetAsync>b__0 (System.Threading.CancellationToken lockedToken) [0x00287] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T] (System.String filePath, System.Func`2[T,TResult] action, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00212] in <2613e7f2f62d4d78a9ca66443392e7f5>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T] (NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceCachedRequest request, System.Func`2[T,TResult] processAsync, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000e7] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3 (NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository source, System.DateTime utcNow, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0020d] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3 (NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository source, System.DateTime utcNow, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x002b1] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.TryCreate (NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository source, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00204] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T] (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000b3] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T] () [0x00067] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpFileSystemBasedFindPackageByIdResourceProvider.TryCreate (NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository sourceRepository, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00079] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T] (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000b3] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T] () [0x00067] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.EnsureResource () [0x00075] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.FindLibraryCoreAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0008a] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider+<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<FindLibraryAsync>b__0 () [0x0007f] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.FindLibraryAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework targetFramework, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00170] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility+<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<FindLibraryFromSourcesAsync>b__0 () [0x00075] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryFromSourcesAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] providers, System.Func`2[T,TResult] action) [0x00160] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryByVersionAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] providers, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00298] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindPackageLibraryMatchAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] remoteProviders, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] localProviders, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002d9] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryMatchAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeIdentifier, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] remoteProviders, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] localProviders, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] projectProviders, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] lockFileLibraries, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00354] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryEntryAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeIdentifier, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteWalkContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000e0] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.CreateGraphNode (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeName, NuGet.RuntimeModel.RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate, NuGet.DependencyResolver.GraphEdge`1[TItem] outerEdge) [0x0020d] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.CreateGraphNode (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeName, NuGet.RuntimeModel.RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate, NuGet.DependencyResolver.GraphEdge`1[TItem] outerEdge) [0x00538] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.WalkDependenciesAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange projectRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeIdentifier, NuGet.RuntimeModel.RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker walker, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteWalkContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000be] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.TryRestoreAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange projectRange, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] frameworkRuntimePairs, NuGet.Repositories.NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] fallbackPackageFolders, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker remoteWalker, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteWalkContext context, System.Boolean forceRuntimeGraphCreation, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, NuGet.Common.TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity) [0x00188] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteRestoreAsync (NuGet.Repositories.NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] fallbackPackageFolders, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteWalkContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, NuGet.Common.TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity) [0x002f1] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x005c8] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAsync (NuGet.Commands.RestoreSummaryRequest summaryRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000c3] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.CompleteTaskAsync (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] restoreTasks) [0x000ce] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunWithoutCommit (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] restoreRequests, NuGet.Commands.RestoreArgs restoreContext) [0x001db] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.DependencyGraphRestoreUtility.PreviewRestoreAsync (NuGet.PackageManagement.ISolutionManager solutionManager, NuGet.ProjectManagement.Projects.BuildIntegratedNuGetProject project, NuGet.ProjectModel.PackageSpec packageSpec, NuGet.ProjectManagement.DependencyGraphCacheContext context, NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommandProvidersCache providerCache, System.Action`1[T] cacheContextModifier, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sources, System.Guid parentId, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001bd] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.PreviewBuildIntegratedProjectActionsAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.Projects.BuildIntegratedNuGetProject buildIntegratedProject, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] nuGetProjectActions, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x004a7] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.PreviewInstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001d7] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0009b] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000d3] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<InstallAsync>b__0 (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000a5] in <5e3b613a5dc34172aa1c0238cc1d0983>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation.InstallInternal (JetBrains.ProjectModel.IProject project, System.String packageId, System.String packgeUserStr, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Configs.NuGetFeedContext feedContext, System.Int32 nestedLevel, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Logging.NuGetNotificationMode mode, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetOperationReporter reporter, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] nativeInstall) [0x003e6] in <5e3b613a5dc34172aa1c0238cc1d0983>:0 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /jonnyzzz/MonoRuntime/Unix/mono/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00048] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronously, Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00262] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c3] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00102] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00322] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00089] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Uri authUri, System.Net.ICredentials credentials, System.Boolean preAuthenticate, System.Boolean isProxyAuth, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool pool, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00112] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ba] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ca] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.ServerWarningLogHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0007f] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.StsAuthenticationHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000bc] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceAuthenticationHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c1] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x000b3] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.TimeoutUtility.StartWithTimeout[T] (System.Func`2[T,TResult] getTask, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.String timeoutMessage, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001bd] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandler.SendAsync (NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandlerRequest request, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x004a0] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetThrottledResponse (System.Func`1[TResult] requestFactory, System.TimeSpan requestTimeout, System.TimeSpan downloadTimeout, System.Int32 maxTries, System.Guid sessionId, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d6] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1[T].<GetAsync>b__0 (System.Threading.CancellationToken lockedToken) [0x00287] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T] (System.String filePath, System.Func`2[T,TResult] action, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00212] in <2613e7f2f62d4d78a9ca66443392e7f5>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T] (NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceCachedRequest request, System.Func`2[T,TResult] processAsync, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000e7] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3 (NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository source, System.DateTime utcNow, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0020d] in <d4203dc3a8164456b8554ec41feb822b>:0 
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /jonnyzzz/MonoRuntime/Unix/mono/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00048] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronously, Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00262] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c3] in <9dc23467daed4410af80fc743b27de41>:0 
Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /jonnyzzz/MonoRuntime/Unix/mono/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00048] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in <83ba76ce532948a980b363df025cb9eb>:0 

[Notification][Install] Install failed (project: Schedulerer.Domain, package: LanguageExt.Core v1.9.7)
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
```

Everything works fine if I install packages using dotnet command through terminal.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to update/install mono. It now works as expected.